# Name of product of dimensions of matrix

Tags: matrices, terminology

We have a matrix of dimensions $m×n$.

Does the product $p=m*n$ have a special name?

It is of course number of items of matrix.

If it has no special name in math, how would you call it if you have to refer to it be words.

Like capacity of matrix, for example, but it is quite ridiculous.

Same thing for a grid... if we have a grid of `m` rows and `n` columns how would you call `p=m*n`?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no special name for the number of entries in a matrix. But you could still define it as $p=m*n$.